# Static linking with modified LGPL code

Tags: licensing, lgpl

I'm writing a library which links with modified LGPL library,so two questions:

1. Do I have to make my code LGPL in case of static linking with LGPL library?
2. in case of dynamic linking?

Answer (score 2):

First, note that your *modifications to the LGPL library* are under the LGPL.

With respect to code that *uses* the LGPL library, the [FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#LGPLStaticVsDynamic) should answer your question:

> (1) If you statically link against an LGPL'd library, you must also provide your application in an object (not necessarily source) format, so that a user has the opportunity to modify the library and relink the application.
>
> (2) If you dynamically link against an LGPL'd library already present on the user's computer, you need not convey the library's source. On the other hand, if you yourself convey the executable LGPL'd library along with your application, whether linked with statically or dynamically, you must also convey the library's sources, in one of the ways for which the LGPL provides.

Comment: how does "(not necessarily source)" and "user has the opportunity to modify the library" go together???

Comment: @TacB0sS: "(not necessarily source)" applies to *your application*, whereas "has the opportunity to modify" applies to *the library*.

Comment: @TacB0sS: It means that if you statically link MyApp.obj to SomeLgplLibrary.lib to create MyApp.exe, you need to provide MyApp.obj, so that the user can replace SomeLgplLibrary.lib with SomeCompatibleLgplLibrary.lib and re-link MyApp.exe.

Comment: I think I get it but I'v ask a more specific question just to be clear on my situation http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/237247/using-lgpl-library-with-java-static-or-dynamic-linking